# Animation not working on IE

Tags: html, css, svg

I made an SVG logo for a website which I'm trying to animate now and it works great on Firefox and Chrome but for some reason when I load it on IE it is treated as a normal image and does nothing. Also, in Edge it does the transition between color but not the dash animation. I made a Fiddle with the raw SVG code: [SVG animation Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brunvez/0jxfLod4/). In my page I just put an object and then embed the external .svg file like this:

```
<object>
    <embed id="obj" src="LCF.svg"></embed>
</object>
```

Sorry if this question was already asked but I Googled a lot before asking and I could not find anything to solve this problem, including the -ms- prefix since I use IE 10 not 9

Comment: IE does not support CSS animation of SVG elements, there is no solution other than upgrading to Edge. I think there's a known Edge bug on dash animation not working too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Seems like a I was banging my head against a problem with no solution. One more thing, do you happen to know of a way to just show the logo if the viewer uses IE? Like loading another svg but already filled or something

Comment: Sorry, I did not quite understand that last comment. Do you mean that I should change the animation so that all users can experience the same?

Comment: No, set things so that without animation working you get the IE image and make animation work from that state.

Comment: Great alternative. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE won't support CSS animations on SVG. It also won't support SMIL animations which are default for SVG.

**Alternatives-**

1. If it is a logo you're building, you can convert it into GIF(animated) and use GIF instead of SVG.
2. Have a look at [smil2css](https://github.com/webframes/smil2css). It is a utility which converts SMIL to CSS and works in any Internet Explorer version that supports CSS
3. Have a look at [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) . A JavaScript library that allows you to animate web content